# Work with very large arrays in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, memory, memory-management

I am currently working on a problem which involves obtaining the eigenvalues of very large matrices. The matrices are sparse matrices, being NxN and with between N and 2N elements. My problem is that matlab runs out of memory but the computations dont seem to be very hard (the biggest case I can do lasts less than 5 seconds) so since computation time doesn't seem to be an issue I thought maybe this memory issue could be solved with some trick I don't know yet.

I belive that for matlab to diagonalize a matrix. this matrix has to be stored on the RAM memory, could I store a matrix "chunk by chunk" so I end up with a very large matrix on a file on my storage drive and then, if possible, diagonalize it step by step (if I can transform it to box diagonal matrix). Is this a good aproach?

I know that to scale up my problem I would have to begin making aproximations but I am curious how far I can get if I can avoid this memory usage error. Thanks.

Comment: Did you define your matrices as [sparse](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html)? What would be a typical value for `N`?

Comment: What is N, roughly?

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Parallel Computing Toolbox and a cluster, you can store your data in a `distributed` array. The contents of the array will be spread across the memory of the machines in the cluster; nevertheless it will appear to you on your client MATLAB as a single variable.

`eig` works with distributed arrays as well as regular arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can work in matlab with big object inside a matlab file, and work by by part, matlab have a lot of usefool tools for working with big data:

[Big data matlab](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/large-files-and-big-data.html)

In your case you can work as follow (always should be something similar to mapreduce algorithm)

you can save you variables in a mat file

```
A = rand(5);
B = magic(10);
save example.mat A B -v7.3;
clear A B
```

Construct a matlab.io.MatFile object that can load parts of variables from the file, example.mat.

```
example = matfile('example.mat')

example = 

  matlab.io.MatFile

  Properties:
      Properties.Source: C:\Documents\MATLAB\example.mat
    Properties.Writable: false           
                      A: [5x5   double]  
                      B: [10x10 double]
```

Load the first column of B from example.mat into variable firstColB.

```
firstColB = example.B(:,1);
```

then you can work like this

Comment: map reduce does not reduce the amount of RAM needed - it only speeds up the processing speed using parallelism/multiple cores - so I am not sure if Big Data Matlab has anything to do with this. Unless you are suggesting putting this on a cluster/cloud to increase amount of available RAM

Comment: well you ar right I will change the aproach to divide and you will win, so this is the point for the map reduce that I want to say here

Comment: I'm just saying that it seems the OP has a huge sparse matrix that s/he needs to fit in RAM to do computations and s/he needs the whole matrix in order to do the computation, and without more RAM, it seems the only approach is to change the computation function to take less RAM - meaning he needs some kind of customized function - or some kind of estimation to reduce the amount of RAM needed for the operation or get more RAM I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your matrix is declared as sparse, and use an eigenvalue solver that's explicitly designed to work with sparse matrices. The builtin [eigs()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/eigs.html) is one example, and other solvers are available too. For example, [PROPACK](http://sun.stanford.edu/~rmunk/PROPACK/) is explicitly designed for solving large, sparse problems (SVD, or eigenvalue decomposition when the matrix is symmetric). Don't request more eigenvalues than you actually need (specify whether you want the largest or smallest). `eigs()` can also take a function as input instead of a matrix, where the function returns the result of the matrix acting on a given vector. You might be able to use this to reduce memory. For example, if your matrix has some known structure that can be used to compute this function without ever explicitly representing the matrix. Or, you might be able to rig up a way to store the matrix on disk and load only parts of it at a time to compute this function (but you will pay with time).

If solving the eigenvalue problem is only a step for some other problem, it may be possible to avoid it in some cases. For example, PCA can be solved using an eigendecomposition of the covariance matrix. But, in some cases it's much more efficient (in terms of both time and memory) to solve it another way (e.g. online updating/incremental learning, or using the SVD). If this is applicable to your problem, it could be worth looking into.

If you're willing to sacrifice accuracy, you could also try using single-precision numbers instead of the usual doubles (`eigs()` doesn't support this, but an external solver might).

Answer (score -1):

everything is stored in RAM in Matlab, unless you can perform the calculation without seeing the entire matrix - you will face the RAM issue anyways. My suggestions are:

1, if your data are Ints or some data form that takes less space than a Double(Float). You may consider converting it in to a Matrix of uint8 or something.

2, Buy more RAM

funny alternative is to [download more RAM](http://www.downloadmoreram.com)

Also check how much memory you are using:

```
[userview systemview] = memory
```

3, maybe you can close some processes you are running (other than Matlab) to release some memory for Matlab (JVM). Also, in Matlab, delete any variable that you do NOT need (or save them and then delete them using `clear`).

4, If you are using Unix `-nojvm`, it is possible to start Matlab without JVM (which is a RAM monster), but this will come at the cost of losing all Java functionality, I am not sure about which functions you are using, as I do not have the code, but it is worth a try.

5, you may also consider running virtual RAM and Increase your system Swap Space - this is the potentially 512TB of disk space that can be used as temp storage - but this method frequently fails and is not recommended. If you use SSD, it will lay heavy burden and waste it in no time at all. If you are using HDD, you run a similar threat.

BUT I am afraid all of these method will not fundamentally solve your problem - since in Big data land, the data only get bigger, without larger RAMs, your only other way is through estimation or a more RAM efficient computation process (this is tricky no?). So if you data gets larger, perhaps using Cloud clusters where you can have virtually infinite RAM is perhaps the best solution.

Comment: Interesting, I humbly await the down voters to provide a viable solution, because I cannot :(